# How many students are in both basketball and soccer teams?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A school with 14 students has a basketball team with 5 players,4 players in chess,7 in netball and 11 in soccer.

Each student joins at least 1 club.
Only one student,Hawa plays chess,netball and soccer.
There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and chess.
There is exactly 1 student who plays basketball and netball.
Hawa is the only one who plays chess and netball.
There are 3 students(including Hawa) who plays chess and soccer.
There are 5 students(including Hawa) who play netball and soccer.

How many play basketball and soccer?

I did this manually and drew out the slots for each member in each team and I got 3 students.But I'm pretty sure there's a mathematical way of doing this using combinations perhaps.Can someone post the working?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A, B, C, D$ be the sets of students who play netball, basketball, chess, and soccer, respectively. Then we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$\begin{align}
&|A\cup B\cup C\cup D|\\
&=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|\\
&-(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\cap D|+|B\cap C|+|B\cap D|+|C\cap D|)\\
&+(|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap D|+|A\cap C\cap D|+|B\cap C\cap D|) \\
&-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting the values we know:

$$\begin{align}
&14\\
&=7+5+4+11\\
&-(1+1+5+1+|B\cap D|+3)\\
&+(0+0+1+0) \\
&-0\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore $|B\cap D| = 3$